# Accessing containerised API hosted on digital ocean droplet from a remote machine

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-network

I am trying to connect to a docker-compose deployed service stack on a DigitalOcean Docker droplet. It contains a MySQL container with a database and a go/alpine container with the API. I am using a custom bridge network which the 2 containers connect to. The issue also occurred when trying to deploy the stack locally on my mac and accessing the API container via localhost:port. I am not using docker-machine as I assume it only is needed for multi-host deployments. The stack is deployed successfully. The server container seems to be able to connect to the DB container. I am wondering if the issue might be within the host's firewall rules?

I did try to run the app locally with mysql server running on my machine and it does work, so I don't think the reason is malfunctioning code. I couldn't get it to work either with basic HTTP server nor with https with self-signed certificates (both work on my local machine).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  net:
    attachable: true

services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ENV=local
    networks:
      - net
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
      - "443:5001"
    networks:
      - net
    tty: true
    links:
      - db:db
```

iptables -L with the stack deployed:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.2           tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.3           tcp dpt:5001
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.3           tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ufw-user-limit  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 30 hit_count: 6 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ufw-user-limit-accept  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2375
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2376

Chain ufw-user-limit (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**UPDATE:**

I have 3 json files with configs & credentials for different environments that are parsed into a config object with the following format (credentials substituted for obvious reasons):

```
{
  "server": {
    "certificate": "<HTTPS_CERT>.pem",
    "key": "<HTTPS_KEY.pem",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "5000",
    "protocol": "http://",
    "file_protocol": "bfile://"
  },
  "database": {
    "address": "db",
    "port": "3306",
    "name": "brieefly",
    "user": "<USERNAME>",
    "password": "<PASSWORD>"
  },
  "auth": {
    "public": "<JWT_AUTH_KEY>.rsa.pub",
    "private": "<JWT_AUTH_PRIV_KEY>.rsa"
  }
}
```

The config is then passed to a db object and a router object:

db:

```
// connect to db - this succeeds

func Connect(config *config.Config) (*DB, *err.Error) {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@(%s:%s)/%s?parseTime=true",
        config.Database.User,
        config.Database.Password,
        config.Database.Address,
        config.Database.Port,
        config.Database.Name)
    log.Debug(connectionString)
    db, sqlErr := sql.Open("mysql", connectionString)
    if sqlErr != nil {
        return nil, err.New(sqlErr, err.ErrConnectionFailure, nil)
    }
    sqlErr = db.Ping()
    if sqlErr != nil {
        return nil, err.New(sqlErr, err.ErrConnectionFailure, nil)
    }
    return &DB{db}, nil
}

.
.
.
```

router:

```
.
.
.

// Run - starts the server
func (r *Router) Run() *err.Error {
    path := config.MyPath(r.config)
    var httpErr error

    if r.config.Environment == config.Local {
        httpErr = http.ListenAndServe(path, r.mux)
    } else {
        httpErr = http.ListenAndServeTLS(path, r.config.TLSCert(), r.config.TLSKey(), r.mux)
    }

    return err.New(httpErr, err.ErrInternal, nil)
}

.
.
.
```

main function:

```
// since the db container needs time to start mysql server daemon, the app is retrying the connection infinitely until it succeds, *router.Run()* is a blocking operation.

func main() {
    retry.PerformInfinite(retry.DefaultOptions(), func() *err.Error {
        log.Info("Configuring...")
        c, cErr := config.NewConfig(config.Local)
        if cErr != nil {
            log.Error(cErr)
            return cErr
        }
        log.Info("Configuration successful.")

        log.Info("Connecting to database...")
        db, dbErr := db.Connect(c)
        if dbErr != nil {
            log.Error(dbErr)
            return dbErr
        }
        log.Info("Connected.")

        router := net.NewRouter(db, c)


        log.Info("Server is running.")
        log.Info("Accepting standard input -> ")
        rtErr := router.Run()
        if rtErr != nil {
            log.Error(dbErr)
            return rtErr
        }

        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: You should be able to run this on a Docker Desktop setup without worrying about firewall configuration at all.  (Except IIRC the Mac setup doesn't let you bind to "low" ports and you'll need to pick different port numbers.)  Can you show the bit of the application that binds to the network socket?

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: If you set `server.ip` to 0.0.0.0, does it work better?  (In general in Docker, if you **bind**(2) to 127.0.0.1, a service will be unreachable from outside its own container.)

Comment: Omg, it works, thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Docker generally the localhost 127.0.0.1 address means "this container".  If you start a server process and tell it to listen on 127.0.0.1, it will only accept connections originating from within the same container.  You almost always want to set servers to listen on the magic 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address, at which point they will be able to accept connections from other containers and the host.

In your setup, this just involves changing the configuration value `"server": {"ip": "0.0.0.0"}`.